# GeoNode 2.6 - Remove map and layers thumbnail?

Tags: geonode

[image: Layer Thumbnail is not showing up]

When set a layer thumbnail and 500 error occurs. I am not sure what's going on. The quick fix may be just to remove the thumbnails from the layer and maps list page layout. Somehow this layout page, panels.html couldn't be located on the ubuntu server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There´s a usefull command that solved me many thumbs problems in GeoNode.

```
$ geonode delete_orphaned_thumbs
```

or

```
$ python manage.py delete_orphaned_thumbs
```

If necessary restart apache after that.
Also when updating thumbs does not work, run this comamnd and set the thumb again.
Hope it helps